# How to use Marionette.CompositeView for form elements collection, based on validated models

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a phone model and collection of phones. Marionette.CompositeView used for rendering collection of phones form elements and Marionette.ItemView for rendering input.

CompositeView listens event from .add-phone button add adds to collection empty phone model, but Backbone.Collection validates my model on add event and throws exeption.

How to use standart validator in my phone model and Marionette views for adding new empty phone form element ?

```
Uncaught Error: Can't add an invalid model to a collection
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6hRN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different options. You can allow the validation to pass a PhoneModel which doesn't have a "number" property set at all:

```
    validate: function() {

        if(_.has(this.attributes, 'number'))
            return;

        return this.get('number').length == 0;
    }
```

This will still fail models, which have the `number` attribute set to be an empty string.

Alternatively you can provide a separate section in your template for adding new items, and create a model only after the user has clicked the Add button. Something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Kp2/).